# Robot -how to continue on failure but highlight the failure in report using python script not from keywords

Tags: python, testing, automation, robotframework

In Robot Framework I am writing custom libraries , Iam able to fail the test case by rasing exception inside the python script but how to continue on failure but highlight the failure in report using python script not from keywords Please help if anyone know

Comment: What do you mean by highlight failure in log . Do you need a way to log the information to log.html ?

Comment: Should be able to see as its a failure in log.html then still tests should continue, so that once i check the log i should be able to figure out where was the failure, and these all can be done in python? Not from Robot file